# how to post textbox value to web api

Tags: json, api, serialization

I have a TextBox with json format already I wanted this value to be posted in the web api via the code below

```
public string CreateInvoice()
        {
            {
                // string token = string.Empty;
                string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                    {
                      // the value in form1 textbox2.text?

                    });

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    strResponseValue = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    //NameValueCollection urlParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponseValue);
                    //token = urlParameters["token"];
                }
                return strResponseValue;
            }
        }
```

Expecting this textbox value to be added this is the textbox below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLyTD.jpg)

this is the Value of the textbox
{
"retailer_br_id": "5473177",
"retailer_external_id": "",
"erp_invoice_number": "17238",
"invoice_date": "2022-07-29T00:07:00.000Z",
"status": 1,
"total_tax": 283.49,
"total_value": 2645.95,
"invoice_level_discount": 0,
"details": [
{
"sku_external_id": "000005011200201132",
"quantity": 1,
"price_per_item": 2069.95,
"sku_uom": "CS"
},
{
"sku_external_id": "000005011200208371",
"quantity": 12,
"price_per_item": 48.0,
"sku_uom": "PCK"
}
]
}